# How to tell if a C# project can only be opened in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a massive* C# solution recently handed to me that I am trying to straighten out and get to correctly work.  The vast majority of it was developed in Visual Studio 2012 and open with it just fine.  But I am unable to open a few projects, and Visual Studio isn't able to tell me why.  So I'm wondering if there is some simple way to check if these projects that weren't able to be opened were developed in VS 2013.

*massive based on projects I've worked on; YMMV.

Comment: If VS couldn't open a solution because of the version, it would say so. You can safely assume this is not the problem. What error/message is display when you are 'unable to open' the projects?

Comment: If it is of any help, it does say 'Unsupported' and says because my version (VS 2012) cannot open them because either they are not supported or the project types are now installed.  But I was wondering if there is a way of looking at the project file that would explicitly mark it as a 2013 project.

Comment: If you open the solution file in notepad you will see the VS version name near the top.

Comment: If you open the .sln in notepad file you'll find a line which contains the version of VS used to create it (somehing like `# Visual Studio 2012`) but for project files you only have the version of .NET (`Project ToolsVersion="4.0"`) so they can be opened with any VS that supports that version. What is the extension of your project file? Is it .csproj?

Comment: Here for me, VS 2012 and VS 2013 Express open with no problem interchangeably.

Comment: It is a .csproj.  There is an 'ToolsVersion' set to 3.5.

Comment: Then the project was probably developed with VS 2008, you should be able to migrate it to VS 2012 with no problem.

Comment: I've migrated projects before and this is saying it can't migrate it.

Comment: @Ovidiu It appears your comment is the correct answer in so far as 'you can't just by looking at the project'.

Comment: @Lawtonfogle Do you have .net 3.5 installed or just 4.5? Try editing the .csproj file in notepad and replace ToolsVersion="3.5" with ToolsVersion="4.0". See if VS opens it.

Comment: I hate 3.5, 4.0, and 4.5 installed.